# Definir uma variável de sessão clicando em um link

Tags: php, session

Tenho uma lista dropdown, que permite escolher o ano que será utilizado na pesquisa da base de dados. Gostaria que o utilizador ao seleccionar uma dessas datas,  defini-se uma variável de sessão com o valor do ano, e assim ser possível utilizar essa variável em futuras pesquisas à base de dados.

```
<li class="dropdown" id="teste">
    <a style="color:white;"href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
       role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       2016 <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Se possível que não muda-se de página, mas se for obrigatório não será, para mim, impeditivo a sua utilização.

Comment: Esse dropdown é do bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alterando um pouquinho sua estrutura para:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a style="color:white;"href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    2016 <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul id="alterar-ano" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-ano="2015" href="#">2015</a></li>
        <li><a data-ano="2016" href="#">2017</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Um *script* em javascript usando jQuery para executar a sessão de forma invisível.

```
<script>
    $("#alterar-ano li").click(function(event){
        // pega o ano selecionado pelo evento do clique
        var value = $(this).data("ano");
        // executa uma função em ajax direcionando para outra página em PHP que irá trocar a sessão
        var url = "alterarSessaoDoAno.php";
        $.post(url, {ano: value}, 
        function(retorno){
            // ...
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

</script>
```

Arquivo externo com a função para alterar a sessão:

**alterarSessaoDoAno.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // aqui você personaliza o nome da sessão de acordo com o que já tem (se tiver).
    $_SESSION['ano'] = $_POST['ano'];
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
?>
```

É isso! Dessa forma, no clique da opção do ano, de forma invisível ao usuário e sem piscar a página, ele vai alterar a sessão do ano.

Comment: Quando tento ver o valor de `value` ele dá undefined: `var value = $(this).data("ano");
                alert(value);` Deveria dar o ano que seleccionei, Correcto?

Comment: Tente trocar `$("#alterar-ano li")` por `$("#alterar-ano [data-ano]")` e tente ver o resultado do `alert`.